# Bind Count of ItemsSource of an ItemsControl in a TextBlock using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemssource

I want to bind a Count of ItemsSource of an ItemsControl in a TextBlock using WPF.

Have a Look into my tried Code

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.ItemsSource.Item, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </MenuItem.Header>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2" MinWidth="100">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

> Note: I need to get the count based on **`ItemsControl ItemsSource`** not  by the `Collection.Count` Property. Kindly assist me.

Comment: What stopping you from getting the `Count` of `PersonCollection` instead of `ItemsSource`?

Comment: @Gopichandar I'm using this within a Custom Control. So, I need to take decision based on ItemsSource Count. Kindly assist me as per my requirement.

Comment: Give a try on `Path=Items.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
 <Menu>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControl, Path=Items.Count,  Mode=OneWay}" />
            </MenuItem.Header>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    MinWidth="100">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.Text}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: I need to get the count based on `ItemsControl ItemsSource` not by the `Collection.Count` Property. Kindly assist me.

Comment: It is the same value. the same number

Comment: Yes both are same. But I need as like that,

Comment: I can't able to get any count. The TextBlock was inside the Menu Header...

Comment: I just have run this code on my solution - it works.
However, you can't update your items count, it is due to the fact that this property is readonly and you have to make it  Mode=OneWay.